# Работа с базой данных с помощью ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Есть html код, он должен с помощью аякса взаимодействовать с пхп файлом:

```
<form id="myForm">  
<br/> <input id="username" type="submit" value="Принять"><br/><br/>

</form>  

<div id="content"></div>  

<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){  

        $('#myForm').submit(function(){  
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "greetings.php",  
                data: "username="+$("#username").val(),  
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#content").html(html);  
                }  
            });  
            return false;  
        });  

    });  
</script>
```

При нажатии на кнопку передаются данные из greetings.php. Этот файл отбирает по ключам данные из бд, например, мы нажимаем на кнопку, отбираются данные, показываются результаты(5-6 штук) по которым тоже можно кликать(php создает кликабельные ссылки), и они опять будут отбирать данные.

Вот кусок greetings.php, в остальном файле меняется только критерий отбора

```
if ((!$code) && (!$record) && (!$name) && (!$parent_code)){ // отображаем первый уровень
echo "<h3>Данные</h3>";
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mkb.db');
$st = $db->query("select * from class_mkb where parent_id is null and parent_code is null");
$results = $st->fetchAll(); 
foreach ($results as $res){
    echo "<a href='greetings.php?parent_code=".$res['code']."'>".$res['name']."</a>";
    if (strlen($res['additional_info']) >0) echo " (<a href='mkbinfo.php?id=".$res['id']." ' target='_blank'>?</a>)";
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Т.е файл обращается к бд, она выдает результаты по ключам, пхп создает кликабельные ссылки, отправляет их на html страницу, и так продолжается пока есть результаты. Подскажите пожалуйста, как связать это с аяксом, чтобы страница не перезагружалась полностью при получении новых результатов.

Постарался объяснить как можно более понятно, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: в форме что-то ещё есть кроме кнопки "Принять"?

Comment: В аяксе вы пропустили параметр dataType: "html" тогда сформированный пыхой хтмл можно будет вставить на страницу.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то проблема в том, что при нажатии на вновь пришедшие ссылки страница перезагружается.
Для того чтобы при клике данные отправлялись аяксом вам надо определить еще один аякс-обработчик для ссылок.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.ajax-btn', function(){ // желательно добавить таким ссылкам класс
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function(html){  
      $("#content").html(html);  
    }  
  });  
  return false; 
});
```

Также более удобно вместо

```
data: "username="+$("#username").val(),
```

использовать

```
data: $(this).serialize(), // $(this) должно быть формой
```